# prolog read from file throws error on special characters

Tags: prolog, readfile

I am working in Prolog, and am trying to read in from a file. The first line is a password. With the password, I want to be able to use special characters.

Here is the read file code:

```
readfile(Filename):-  
    open(Filename, read, Str),  
    read(Str, Thepassword),  
    read(Str, Thefirewall),  
    close(Str),   
    nb_setval(password, Thepassword),  
    nb_setval(firewall, Thefirewall).
```

This works fine until I change the password from brittany to britta!y, then I get `ERROR: computer1.txt:1: Syntax error: Operator expected`.

Anyone know what I should do?

Comment: `read` doesn't read strings but Prolog terms.

Comment: As @dlask says, `read/2` reads Prolog terms (see [the documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/2)). You need to show what your input file actually looks like. What you had that worked happened to be proper Prolog terms. But no longer when you introduced the `!` symbol.

Comment: Using `nb_setval/2` as you do is clearly abuse. It is quite deplorable that certain Prolog systems provide this functionality too easily.

Answer (score 2):

`read/2` reads Prolog terms. What you probably want is to read the whole line regardless it is in Prolog syntax or not.

In SWI Prolog you can use the predicate `read_line_to_codes/2` instead. (See the [SWI manual entry](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=readutil)). You must include the library with `use_module(library(readutil))` first.

SICStus has a similar predicate called [`read_line/1/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dread_005fline.html).

If you need an atom instead of a list of codes, you can convert it with `atom_codes/2`.